# prevent jQuery animate() reset on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fade out all menu items exept the one the user hovers over. When using jQuery's `animate()` function on the opacity property it kind of works.

I set the opacity of all menu items exept the hovered to .25, and when I hover off it looks great, but when I hover directly over another item, the opacity off all items is reset to 1, and then animated down to .25.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Can you include your code?

Comment: Also, depending on your exact usage, CSS transitions for opacity may be better than jQuery.